# Why am I unable to wrap a figure environment with newenviron?

Tags: environments

This looks like a fairly simply way to wrap the `figure` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newenviron}
\newenviron{myenv}{
    \begin{figure}
        \envbody
    \end{figure}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}
    Hi!
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

However, I get this:

```
Incomplete \ifcsname; all text was ignored after line 11.
<inserted text>
```

I have seen examples where `figure` is first renamed (with `\let`) and then renewed; but what is wrong with my example?

Comment: The command `\newenviron` wants *two* mandatory arguments, like `\newenviroment`.

Comment: @egreg well, don't I give it two arguments in my code?

Comment: Two arguments besides the environment's name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the *first* error:

```latex
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.8 \begin{d
            ocument}
?
```

What's the problem? The terse documentation of the package states

```
% \newenviron<optional *>
%   {<name>}[<narg>][<default of 1st argument>]{<start-code>}{<end-code>}
```

which indicates that the syntax is the same as for `\newenvironment`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newenviron}
\newenviron{myenv}{
    \begin{figure}
        \envbody
    \end{figure}
}{}%<--- nothing at end

\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}
    Hi!
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

I suggest to use `xparse` instead:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{O{htp}+b}{%
    \begin{figure}[#1]
        #2
    \end{figure}
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{myenv}
    Hi!
\end{myenv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oooooooooh. So are you saying that when I used `\makeatletter\newenviron{test}{\some@cmd}\makeatother`, `\newenviron` ate that `\makeatother`? And that explains why I was still able to use `\some@cmd` in my document, although I shouldn't? Thanks!